# How to set up centralized Management entity to control Hostapd access points

Tags: hostapd

We are working on a project to provide wifi at our university. Due to financial limits, we are planning to install multiple linux based access points (wlan modules running with hostapd). But at the moment we are confused to proceed that: **Is there any way to impliment ubuntu based wireless lan controller for centralized management of such access points?**

Though, the CAPWAP protocol has been standardized by IETF for the communication between access points and wlan controler but **"Does hostapd support CAPWAP/LWAPP or not?"**

please help us in this regard,

Comment: well!, we ll look into Landscape/Puppet/Chef/Ansible, untill now we  were looking for the incorporation CAPWAP/LWAPP with Hostapd.  But we are afraid that we ll not have full ubuntu installation on our linux device (AP). The idea is to implemnet WLAN controller functions (authnetication, handover, etc.) on a a PC and controll/configure these AP with it,

Comment: Sorry, I misread that part in your question. Removed earlier comment.